# Replace ^A with space in Linux

Tags: linux, unix, awk, linux-kernel, tr

How can we replace `^A` with space in Linux:

```
1528773495.945011914 : 8=FIX.4.2^A35=0^A108=20^A49=36593^A56=NSE^A10=000^A
```

I want my output to look like as below:

```
1528773495.945011914 : 8=FIX.4.2 35=0 108=20 49=36593 56=NSE 10=000
```

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions that have been asked and answered so many times you have to make an effort to avoid finding an answer. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score -1):

Ok so this worked for me.

```
"1528773495.945011914 : 8=FIX.4.2^A35=0^A108=20^A49=36593^A56=NSE^A10=000^A" | tr '\1' ' '
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to replace characters in a string in Linux is to use `awk`. Specifically, `awk '{gsub(/\^A/," ")}1'` will replace all occurrences of `^A` with a blank space.

```
echo "1528773495.945011914 : 8=FIX.4.2^A35=0^A108=20^A49=36593^A56=NSE^A10=000^A"\
 |awk '{gsub(/\^A/," ")}1'

1528773495.945011914 : 8=FIX.4.2 35=0 108=20 49=36593 56=NSE 10=000
```